# What algorithm is implemented in OpenCV contour detection?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

Does anyone know which algorithm is implemented in the OpenCV library to perform the contour detection? Can you possibly give me a reference too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation to `cv::findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0):

> The function retrieves contours from the binary image using the algorithm [Suzuki85]. The contours are a useful tool for shape analysis and object detection and recognition.

And:

> [Suzuki85] Satoshi Suzuki and others. Topological structural analysis of digitized binary images by border following. Computer Vision, Graphics, and Image Processing, 30(1):32–46, 1985.

The DOI for this paper is [10.1016/0734-189X(85)90016-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/0734-189X(85)90016-7)