# haw the function cvFindContours work?

Tags: opencv

I'm using the `cvFindContours` function in C++ and OpenCV.

I have to make a documentation of the function I'm using, can someone tell me how this function works, which method for find contours uses and if it possible some theory at the basis of the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV Contour Detection which implemented algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334166/opencv-contour-detection-which-implemented-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29): *"The function retrieves contours from the binary image using the algorithm Suzuki85."*

For mor information you can read the whole paper [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aO44VS9e4FgwJ%3atpf-robotica.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Vision/papers/SA-CVGIP.PDF%20&hl=de&gl=de).